# Why does Scala REPL fail with "error: ')' expected but string literal found" for string interpolation?

Tags: scala

Well, I'm  basically trying to do this in my ubuntu 14.04:

```
scala> val test="Hello!"
test: java.lang.String = Hello!
scala>println(s"The message is $test")
```

and I get the error:

```
<console>:1: error: ')' expected but string literal found.
   println(s"The message is $test")
            ^
```

It should work as I've done some research and it says [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/scala-cookbook/9781449340292/ch01s05.html), that that is the correct form. So what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What is your scala version? Is it something before 2.10?

Comment: My guess is this is using Scala 2.9, as that's the version you get from the ubuntu repositories when using `apt-get`.

Comment: @m-z In that case I think installing the `.deb` from here: http://scala-lang.org/download/2.11.5.html will solve the problem. (Or alternatively using an IDE which includes newer Scala bundled.)

Comment: @GáborBakos My version 2.9.2 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_65).  And I think that installing the latest version would do the trick, but, at my college we must work with that specific version, mentioned above.  Anyhow,  I'm now using     `println("The message is "+test)`     .

Comment: @JeremyCaldwell think the last comment is the answer and should end up as one. Mind doing it and approve ultimately? Thanks!